# Netty 4.x NioEventLoopGroup for Client - Thread Lifecycle and Usage

Tags: netty, nio

We have a Netty client/server based upon 4.x

The client will establish a main channel to the server and communicate back and forth on this single connection.

I would like to understand better the usage of the NioEventLoopGroup threads from a Client perspective.

My setup has very basic pipeline.  SSLHandler, Encoder, Decoder, MessageHandler

Client: I originally thought the thread was used to process incoming data and outgoing data through the pipeline.  However I forced my client to only 1 thread and added a sleep within the channelRead **after** I submit to an executor service(separate thread) to process the incoming message instead of doing so within the channelRead.  That external executor job when its done will write data as a reply to the same channel the data came in on.  The server doesn't get the reply until after the sleep has finished which is what I expected.  However I then increased the client thread to 2.  Ran the same test and server still didn't get a reply until after the 30 seconds.  To verify I added system outs in the job after it wrote the reply to the channel which was output prior to even sleeping.  I expected the second thread to kick in and process the outgoing reply from the job.  So it seems like one client thread is used for a given connection/channel.  Is this accurate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is expected. Each `Channel` is "bound" to one `EventLoop` which is bound to exact one `Thread`. So it does not matter how many `EventLoop`s you have, one `Channel` is only handles by the same `EventLoop` the whole life-time